# Why does InnoDB table by default uses the UNIQUE constraint instead of the PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-5.6, unique-constraint

In my MySQL database I have a table with 4 columns, the `PRIMRAY KEY`, two columns with a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` and one `UNIQUE`  index on all fields except for the `PRIMARY KEY`.

The `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `zdb_userbeschikbaarheid` (
  `UserBeschikbaarheid_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UB_User_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `UB_Datum` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserBeschikbaarheid_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UQ_UB_User_ID_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID_Datum` (`UB_Datum`,`UB_User_ID`,`UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID`),
  KEY `FK_UB_User_ID` (`UB_User_ID`),
  KEY `FK_UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID` (`UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`UB_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID`) REFERENCES `zdb_plandagdeeltaak` (`PlanDagdeelTaak_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_UB_User_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`UB_User_ID`) REFERENCES `zdb_user` (`User_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=522 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For some weird reason when I select the full table it's using the `UNIQUE` index instead of the `PRIMARY KEY`. An `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM zdb_userbeschikbaarheid;` yields:

```
id  select_type table                   type    possible_keys   
1   SIMPLE      zdb_userbeschikbaarheid index   \N

key                                     key_len ref rows    Extra
UQ_UB_User_ID_PlanDagdeelTaak_ID_Datum  11      \N  415     Using index
```

It will not use the `PRIMARY KEY` until I specifically tell it to `ORDER BY` the primary key.
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM zdb_userbeschikbaarheid ORDER BY UserBeschikbaarheid_ID;`

```
id  select_type table                   type    possible_keys
1   SIMPLE      zdb_userbeschikbaarheid index   \N

key     key_len ref rows    Extra
PRIMARY 4       \N  415     \N
```

It just seems odd that the `UNIQUE KEY` is chosen instead of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

What's causing this behavior, is it a potential problem for my database? And if possible, how can I change it to use the `PRIMARY KEY` by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With InnoDB tables, all secondary indexes include the columns of the clustered index (which is the primary key), appended in the end. So your unique index has actually 4 columns, the 3 you have defined plus the 1 primary key column.

When running a query that needs a full table scan, both indexes have all the data needed, so the optimizer is free to choose any one of the two indexes. In fact, as explained in [InnoDB Table and Index Structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html), the clustered index contains some additional information that costs 13 more bytes per row:

> Records in the clustered index contain fields for all user-defined columns. In addition, there is a 6-byte transaction ID field and a 7-byte roll pointer field.

This makes your unique index less wide than the primary key index, which is why it is chosen by the optimizer.